# how to hide xampp apache version number

Tags: apache

I am using xampp(1.8.1) apache server. I would like to hide my Apache Version info when user got 404 pages. I did some research and I know that I should add following two directives in configuration file.

> ServerSignatire Off
>
> ServerTokens Prod

But I am not sure 
1) which file should I edit in xampp apache? 
2) which section/where should I insert these two directives inside file. at the beginning? or at the bottom? I am not clear on these. please help

Thank you

Answer (score 8):

fyi team - after lots of research, for my case - I just access to \xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-default.conf to set "ServerTokens Prod" and "ServerSignature Off". hope this helps! thank you

Comment: Thanks. Have windows 10 XAMPP 1.8.1, was trying to put it in httpd.conf and it doesn't work, but in default.conf it is now working.

Answer (score 0):

following configuration will be added in httpd.conf.
You can add above mention setting in the same file at the bottom.

Comment: User3243699, thank you! would tell me exact where I should insert it into my file. here is the bottom of my file.  I am new here. thank you
#
<IfModule ssl_module>
    SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
    SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

# Configure mod_proxy_html to understand HTML4/XHTML1
#<IfModule proxy_html_module>
#Include etc/extra/proxy-html.conf
#</IfModule>

# AJP13 Proxy
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
<IfModule mod_proxy_ajp.c>
Include "conf/extra/httpd-ajp.conf"
</IfModule>
</IfModule>